# Magento2 in After order placed Observer does not change order status

Tags: sales-order, payment-gateway, magento-2.1

```
class AfterSaveOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Sets current instructions for bank transfer account
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_NEW, true);
        $order->setStatus('new');
        $order->save();
     }
}
```

Comment: Does it go in an endless loop?

Comment: just see logic..now set endloop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the order repository to save the order.

Include the class in your constructor:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository
 */
public $orderRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}
```

And then within the execute method:

```
/**
 * Sets current instructions for bank transfer account
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_NEW, true);
    $order->setStatus('new');
    //$order->save();
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);
 }
```

Comment: I added that piece of code in the observer implementing "sales_order_save_before" but it gives error header set twice and still the order have processing state